# Behavior of google chrome extensions on different OS?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been working on Chrome Extensions. Is there any difference in behavior related to working, execution or implementation of extensions on different platforms like Windows, Mac or Linux? If so, What are the limitations to set so that same extension could run on all platforms?

Comment: Generally the behavior is identical. Otherwise your question lacks specifics.

Comment: I couldn't find any article regarding any differences as so but I wanted to confirm if anyone may have worked on windows and mac extensions at the same time.

Comment: It's because there are no differences generally unless you bump into something really weird/specific.